# Slide instead of Fade for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This could be a simple thing I'm sure...

I'm trying to get the `fade` to `slide`:

`$slides.eq($btns.index(this)).fadeIn().siblings().hide();`

At the moment, it works great with `fade`, I just need this line tweaked to `slide`.  I've done the obvious but I must be doing something with the syntax as it doesn't work.

Cheers in advance!

//added

```
var
$btns = $('.btns a'),
$slides = $('.slides > div');

$btns.click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('current')
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('current');
  $slides.eq($btns.index(this)).fadeIn(function(){ slideIn }).siblings().hide();
  return false;
});
$btns.first().click();

  <div class="slides">
    <div>Slide 1</div>
    <div>Slide 2</div>
    <div>Slide 3</div>
    <div>Slide 4</div>
    <div>Slide 5</div>
    <div>Slide 6</div>
  </div>

  <ul class="btns">
    <li class="one"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="four"><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="five"><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li class="six"><a href="#">6</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a normal slide, use [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), like this:

```
$slides.eq($btns.index(this)).slideDown().siblings().slideUp();
```

[You can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/N7hSF/)

---

If instead you want a fade + slide type of effect, pass a speed parameter to [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), like this:

```
$slides.eq($btns.index(this)).show('slow').siblings().hide('slow');
```

[You can test that effect here](http://jsfiddle.net/N7hSF/1/)

Comment: I think he wants to slide and fade at the same time.

Comment: @griegs - The title says "instead of"...so I provided both options, the second option has a fade/slide combo effect, give it a try :)

Comment: Thanks Nick...perfect...and thanks griegs for your initial help

Answer (score 0):

inside the fadeIn() do the slide.  so something like fadeIn(function(){ slideIn })...

Comment: btw: this all works in firefox but i have had dissapointing results in IE.  IE tends to ignore the animation and simply renders everything at the end.  that was in the previous version of jQuery tho

Comment: Hey thanks, do you mean like this? $slides.eq($btns.index(this)).fadeIn(function(){ slideIn }).siblings().hide();

Comment: Not sure about a lot of that code actually.  Seems a little long.  Could you post the html you are trying to hide and slide as i think the code can be a lot simpler.

Comment: I amended my initial post.  Thanks for your help griegs