# Get text to slide in from right instead of from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I took the code from [Slide instead of Fade for a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097708/slide-instead-of-fade-for-a-div) and I'm trying to have the text slide in from the right instead of sliding from the top. Also, is there another way for it to auto slide and continue looping after it's done?

Here's the HTML:

```
 <div class="slides">
    <div>test 1</div>
    <div>test 2</div>
    <div>test 3</div>
    <div>test 4</div>
    <div>test 5</div>
    <div>test 6</div>
  </div>

  <ul class="btns">
    <li class="one"><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a href="#">test 3</a></li>
    <li class="four"><a href="#">test 4</a></li>
    <li class="five"><a href="#">test 5</a></li>
    <li class="six"><a href="#">test 6</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Here's the Jquery:

```
var $btns = $('.btns a'), $slides = $('.slides > div');

$btns.click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('current')
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('current');
  $slides.eq($btns.index(this)).slideDown().siblings().slideUp();
  return false;
});
$btns.first().click();
```

Here's also a link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1c82yyt7/

Comment: I'm not good with this stuff but you can try with jQuery.animate, you'll need to pass the new CSS rule to move the coordenates to the right and it will animate it.

Answer (score 0):

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/x17obfnu/)?

**CODE**

```
var $btns = $('.btns a'), $slides = $('.slides > div');

$btns.click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('current')
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('current');
    $slides.eq($btns.index(this)).animate({"width":"toggle"},1000).siblings().hide();
    return false;
});
$btns.first().trigger('click');
```